# Regex that matches if first part of string matches second part of string

Tags: regex

Was wondering if there was a one line regex that can test whether the first match is in the rest of the string.  For example: I'd like to know when progress is finished.  The last 3 lines of the output is:

```
Transferring 299 of 301 records.
Transferring 300 of 301 records.
Transferring 301 of 301 records.
```

Amount varies.

Is there a way to test so the last line matches the regex?

Comment: What language or tool? What should be matched? and what is expected output?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
Transferring( [0-9]*) of\1+ records.
```

\1 matches the same text as most recently matched by the 1st capturing group.
See here: https://regex101.com/r/7EEZGa/1

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Transferring ([0-9]+) of \1 records\.`

Explanation:

- `Transferring` - Matches literally.
- `([0-9]+)` - Captures one or more digits.
- `of` - Matches literally.
- `\1` - Matches the digits that were captured in the first capturing group.
- `records\.` - Matches literally (dot is escaped because it is a wildcard character).

Can be tested against your input here: https://regex101.com/r/jkYZh3/1